# Creating Client Certificate - Windows

Tags: windows, certificate

I am trying to create client certifications against a Microsoft CA using the built in website. (Microsoft Active Directory Certificate Services) From what I can tell, you have to login as the user to create the corresponding certificate.

Is there any way to get around that? I tried to create my own template, duplicating the user template, but it doesn't match and gets rejected when trying to authenticate. Is this something I'd have to look at building?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I Figured this out. For A CA Server using server 2008 you have to do it via the MMC snap in using your Current User Certificate and not the local computer. Took me awhile to figure that out. You also have to create an enroll agent certificate for yourself. What you do than is right click the personal folder, go to advanced operations and choose enroll on behalf of.

So:

1. Open up mmc and do certificates for your user account.
2. Enroll yourself as a Certificate request agent.
3. right click the personal folder under the certificate
4. Choose Advanced Operations and than Enroll on Behalf of
5. Follow the wizard and the cert will be created

Thanks for all the help

Comment: Which MMC snap in?

Comment: The normal "Certificates" snap-in.  First you have to make sure that the Enrollment Agent certificate template is available in the CA settings, then you have to open the personal Certificate folder in the snap-in as a Domain Admin, and request an Enrollment Agent cert.  Once you have that cert in your personal store, you can use the "Enroll on Behalf" of wizard

Answer (score 2):

Just configure the group policy to "Auto-Enrol" the user/machine certificates

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787781%28WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: The users will only be logging in through a website, otherwise this would work perfectly. Any other ideas by chance?

Comment: This link is now "retired". If anybody wants to edit the answer and include a summary of the relevant information, that'd be nice.